# Inserting Video in HTML Page recorded in IOS

Tags: html, video

I have been asked to add a video to a html page which has been recorded on an iphone.

I have converted the .mov file to .mp4.

My problem is the video rotation is wrongly displayed in internet explorer but in chrome and when played in vlc it is rotated correctly.

Is there anything I can about this - I did rotate the video -90 degrees using video editing software and it plays correctly then in explorer but not in chrome.

Any help appreciated.

This is how I display video in page

```html
<video poster="poster.png" width="320" height="568" controls>
  <source src="cath.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="cath.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="cath.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <object width="640" height="375" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"><!
    [endif]-->
  <!--[if !IE]><!-->
  <object width="320" height="568" type="video/quicktime" data="cath.mp4">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="src" value="cath.mp4" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="showlogo" value="false" />
    <object width="320" height="568" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.swf?image=poster.png&amp;file=cath.mp4">
      <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.swf?image=poster.png&amp;file=cath.mp4&amp;autoStart=false" />
      <img src="poster.png" width="320" height="568" />
      <p>
        <strong>No video playback capabilities detected.</strong>
        Why not try to download the file instead?
        <br />
        <a href="cath.mp4">MPEG4 / H.264 “.mp4” (Windows / Mac)</a> |
        <a href="cath.ogv">Ogg Theora &amp; Vorbis “.ogv” (Linux)</a>
      </p>
    </object>
    <!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</video>
```

Comment: please add your code here

Comment: could somebody explain why I have a down vote - have i posted incorrectly?